# Which steganography method is fit for this problem?

Tags: algorithm, methods, steganography

My task is to embed a hidden watermark into JPEG files. There are a lot of ways how to that. But the problem is ... there are two images in steganography - Original and Original + watermark. There are almost the same.

My problem is to extract the watermark from a screenshot or from a photo of (original + watermark) image.

Does anyone know which methods or algorithms should be used?

Thanks

Comment: I misread the screenshot part.

Comment: Any example input image? You want to remove the watermark too or just encode the watermark as hidden info into JPG but leave the watermark in visible stuff too... removing wattermark is a difficult task especially if the wattermark is unknown and not transparent ...

Comment: As you said I want to encode the watermark as hidden info into JPG. It must be invisible for naked eye. 

OR 

it can be visible for user but it can be represented as pseudochaotic noise.

The problem is that I don't know how to read the hidden data from the (for example) photo of image.